# Laravel with sql server dont save user on register

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to register users with laravel in an existing database. This is made in SQL SERVER. The table is called tb_postulantes and the fields I want to save are nombre_postulante, correo_postulante and password_postulante. The database table contains those same fields and others that for now I do not want to fill with data. When I enter the path /register I complete the fields and the application simply does nothing. It does not save anything in database nor does it throw any error, just reload the page.

I need to be able to save users in the database and then login

[image: DATABASE TABLE]

These are my data

```
RegisterController.php
------------------

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'nombre_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'correo_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
            'password_postulante' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'nombre_postulante' => $data['nombre_postulante'],
            'correo_postulante' => $data['correo_postulante'],
            'password_postulante' => Hash::make($data['password_postulante']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
Model User.php 
---------------
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'tb_postulantes';

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre_postulante', 'correo_postulante', 'password_postulante',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password_postulante', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

```
View register.blade.php
-------------------------

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="nombre_postulante" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre_postulante" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('nombre_postulante')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="correo_postulante" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="correo_postulante" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="correo_postulante" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('correo_postulante')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password_postulante" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password_postulante" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password_postulante" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password_postulante')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password_postulante_confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password_postulante_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_postulante_confirm" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you have xdebug set up an running so that you can debug the application?

Comment: are you sure your `route('register')` is valid route which resolves into a valid http address? check your page's HTML code to find out

Comment: Please share your route file